# Set number of rows in TableView in Titanium

Tags: uitableview, titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to set the number of rows for TableView in Titanium SDK. I searched a lot for alternative of numberofRows method that I usually use in iOS development in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, however, if you are trying to display only 5 rows out of 20, you have to split your large array into 4 arrays, and pass each array of 5 into the tableview, sort of your own pagination.